# How do you pick up the Extra mode up in 1-9, Blue Blunder on the lower path at Rather Difficult?

Tags: runner2

Collecting this powerup isn't hard per-se...

[image]

...but I can't figure out how to do that *and* jump around these little bastards right after.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hate this part, and with good reason; it all comes down to **timing**.

Essentially, you need to spam short bursts of Spacebar (small hops, not floaters or long glides) because once you get past the three little "goombas" (I really don't know what they're called), you'll reach a set of stairs which requires even more spacebar mashing.

[image: Small hops]

To get that extra, I advise using two short hops (after you come out of slide).  After that, it really is timing though.  I've tried to do this, and it is ridiculously hard and crazy (it's why I started using checkpoints)

Good luck!

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: It's more about what happens _after_ I pick up the power-up correctly, when the question is about _how to_ pick up the power-up correctly _and_ skip over the three "goombas".

Comment: @badp No, actually, you need to *"spam short bursts of Spacebar"* to get that powerup. I added a picture to show that better.

Comment: @badp Y U NO ACCEPT